# "Typescript: No overload matches this call error" when I try to add original attributes in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I was making image component using styled-components(below) in typescript-React Project.
[image]

style.ts:
[image]

error says:
[image]

Should I do something in style.ts for accepting attribute?

**Above error also happens when I try to make img styled-component with 'alt' attribute...**

I want to write styled-component but with attribute and with no error.

If you need more files' information, let me know, I will upload my files'.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully recreated your error by messing with the files a bit to create the "no overload matches this call". I created a separate style2.ts file exporting a duplicate ImgUploadForm. Then when I changed the import and deleted style.ts to only use style2.ts that's when I got the error. The error was only solved by restarting vscode and then it worked great again.

In conclusion:

- Double check your import is correct.
- Make sure you aren't already exporting ImgUploadForm from elsewhere as it's not recommended and may cause conflicts when trying to import the same thing from 2 different places.
- restart your editor after you cleanup the code.

Comment: I double checked import and export and also restarted my editor, but there's still a same error in the file....hmm...but Thanks for your help :)